# Get list of objects from GET method on button click and insert into html page table

Tags: javascript, express, server, single-page-application

GET method with the list of cars:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/cars', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json([{
        name :  'a',
        color : 'red'
    },{
        name :  'b',
        color : 'blue'
    }])
})

module.exports = app
```

I'm trying to load the list into my html page=>

When clicking on the button with the `load` id, the list of`cars` on the server is requested; cars with `red` color are loaded into the table with`main` id with a `tr`
 for each car.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A simple app</title>
    <script>
    async function load(){
try{
     let url ='http://localhost:8080/cars'
       let response = await fetch(url)
        let data = await response.json()
        let table = document.getElementById('main')
         table.innerHTML = ''
            for (let e of data){
                 let rowContent = `
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                ${e.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ${e.color}
                            </td>
                        </tr>`
                    let row = document.createElement('tr')
                    row.innerHTML = rowContent
                    //row.dataset.id = e.id
                    table.append(row)
            }
              catch(err){
                    console.warn(err)
                }

}
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    A simple app
    <table id=main></table>
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick={load()} id="load"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: ● local › should load on click

    Error: failed to find element matching selector "#main tr:first-child td:first-child"

      23 |     await page.click('#load')
      24 |     await page.waitForSelector('#main')
    > 25 |     const first = await page.$eval("#main tr:first-child td:first-child", e => e.textContent)

Comment: firstly, you want to change `onClick={load()}`

Comment: then you may run into cors issues depending upon upon your local setup

Comment: I imagine that is the cors issue

Comment: I don't know, maybe my implementation is not correct. Also i need to filter to load only red cars

Comment: is your load function is calling or not ? can you check it by putting some console.logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's few reason why you can't do it, it's because `cors`, `catch` block and `port`.

Maybe you can try this `html` below:

```js
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A simple app</title>
    <script>
    async function load(){

        try {
            let url ='http://localhost:3000/cars';
            let response = await fetch(url);
            let data = await response.json()
            let table = document.getElementById('main');
            table.innerHTML = '';
            for (let e of data){
                let rowContent = `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${e.name}</td>
                        <td>${e.color}</td>
                    </tr>`;
                let row = document.createElement('tr')
                row.innerHTML = rowContent;
                table.append(row);
            }
        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    A simple app
    <table id=main></table>
    <input type="button" value="add" onClick={load()} id="load"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And now, in your server, you can change with this simple server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors( { origin: '*'}));


app.get('/cars', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json([{
      name :  'a',
      color : 'red'
  },{
      name :  'b',
      color : 'blue'
  }])
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: It's working now, i can add the list in my page. But the tests still not pass: failed to find element matching selector "#main tr:first-child td:first-child"

Comment: "But the tests still not pass", I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: I have automatic tests on this exercise.

Comment: I think it's an another topic. You can create new question and asking, why you can run your automatic test. Make sure to provide your code for example.